# Copy word under cursor in tmux?

Tags: tmux, clipboard

I assume this is common operation but can't find any information about this. When in copy mode (Ctrl+[) Is there a shortcut to copy the word under the cursor without manually creating the selection?

I've tried to switch to vi-mode and use yw but it doesn't look like it works (in fact, I'm not entirely sure what vi-mode does besides mapping the arrow keys to hjkl).

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I know it does not answer your question but if you have a mouse with a wheel, double-clicking the word then middle-clicking will paste the word. Temporary work-around, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about text mode? In that case, I don't think it exists with the default settings.

In mouse mode ("set-option -g mouse on"), double-click is mapped to select the word.

If you want to bind a new shortcut, you could do something like (in your .tmux.conf, or test it out via 'Ctrl-b :') :

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-y send-keys -X select-word
```

This will allow control-y to select the word. In this case you will still have to press [Enter] to copy the word and exit copy-mode. If you wanted to do the copy and exit as part of the selection, you can do something like:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-y send-keys -X select-word \; send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
```